# shrinkwrap doesn't go all around a Cylinder

Tags: modifiers, shrinkwrap

So I was trying to `Shrinkwrap` an `Array` to a `Cylinder` and it doesn't go all the way. It only wraps to half of the `Cylinder`. So I looked at how to fix it. I found that you need to kind of help the `Shrinkwrap` by at least making the thing you want to `Shrinkwrap` be closer to the surface of the thing you want the `Shrinkwrap` to stick so I added a `SimpleDeform` so the `Array` would form a circle around the `Cylinder`. But, unfornately, it still only wraps half of it. I tried to lessen the `Array` but it would just make the `Shrinkwrap`ped part stretched and I want to keep the number of `Array` and maybe even increase or decrease it without destroying the `Shrinkwrap`.

[image: before Shrinkwrap]

[image: after Shrinkwrap]

Also, if there's a way I could keep the shape of the ring which the top part is slightly going forward that would be helpful.

UPDATE:
So I tried what @Robin Betts suggested and wasn't able to get the same result the `Target Normal Project` part. I did however got the same result for the `Weight Paint` part but have to redo my topology as I didn't know that it's important for that process

[image: Target Normal Project result]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two questions..

[image]

1. (top row) You're using the wrong projection method in your *Shrinkwrap* modifier for this case.You have 'Project', along Y of the object space of your array (which is the same as the Y of your original element). Better to use 'Target Normal Project' (along the normals of the target) or 'Closest Surface Point'.
2. (bottom row) How to get an outward tilt of the peaks? The *Shrinkwrap* can be modulated by Vertex Weight. Assign a vertex group to the mesh, and weight it with lower values at the peaks. They will be influenced less, if you aim the  *Shrinkwrap* at the group.

Comment: I tried your solution and the 1st part didn't work like yours. The 2nd part worked perfectly but I need to fix my topology first to have a better looking result

Comment: It might depend on other steps.. I don't know how you're deforming your array into a circle .. maybe share your file on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Nvm, my `SimpleDeform` was turned off that's why it's not wrapping up well. Thanks for the help